# C Linked List error not linking properly

Tags: c, pointers, logic

I could not find a similar issue online, mostly since my issue is a little more specific and is probably caused by a logic error of some sort.

I am trying to read in words, one by one (accomplished already) and make a linked list (using typedef, accomplished already) that stores all instances of these words and their frequencies.

What happens is that I get through the first part of the code, the initialization of the linked list, however, the program crashes soon after when it tries to link more nodes.

Here is what happens when I run the code with input:

```
C:\path-->test
hello
First word found: hello
head->word = hello
C:\path--> (Program crashes at this point)
```

my code:
(I have a header file but I decided to put everything in the .c file for simplicity)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
struct LinkedList {
        char* word;
        int count;
        struct LinkedList *next;
};

typedef struct LinkedList *list;
int getNextWord(char* output);
list createNode();
void addEntry(list head, char *entry);
void printList(list head);
void insert(char* dest, char* toAdd);
int compare(char* str1, char* str2);

int main(){
  int length;
  char line[5000];
  list head = NULL;
  while(length = getNextWord(line) > 0){
    printf("First word found: %s\n", line);
    addEntry(head, line);
  }
}


void addEntry(list head, char* entry){
  list temp, p;
  temp = createNode();
  if(head == NULL){
    head = temp;
    insert(head->word, entry);
    printf("head->word = %s", head->word);
    p->next->word = NULL;
    return;
  }
  else{
    p = head;
    printf("Inside else in addEntry");
    while(p->next != NULL){
      if(compare(p->word, entry) == 0){
        p->count = p->count + 1;
        return;
      }
      if(compare(p->word, entry) != 0 && p->word != NULL){
        p = p->next;
      }
      if(compare(p->word, entry) != 0 && p->word == NULL){
        insert(p->word, entry);
        p->count = p->count + 1;
        return;
      }
    }
    p->next = temp;
  }
  return;
}

/* Helper function that creates a node of type (list) */
list createNode(){
  list temp;
  temp = (list)malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList));
  temp->next = NULL;
  return temp;
}
/*list addEntry(list head, char *entry){
  list temp, p;
  temp = createNode();
  if(head == NULL){
    printf("in addEntry head == NULL\n");
    head = temp;
    insert(head->word, entry);
  }
  else {
    printf("in first else case in addEntry\n");
    p = head;
    if((compare(entry, p->word)) == 0 && p->next != NULL){
      p->count = p->count + 1;
      while(0){
        p = p->next;
        if(p->next == NULL){
          p->next = temp;
          return;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    else if((compare(entry, p->word) != 0 && p->next != NULL)){
        printf("in second else case in addEntry");
        p = p->next;
        addEntry(p, entry);
      }
    else if(p->word == NULL){
      insert(p->word, entry);
      p->count = p->count + 1;
      p->next = temp;
    }
    else if((compare(entry, p->word) != 0 && p->next == NULL)){
      p->next = temp;
      insert(p->word, entry);
      p->count = p->count + 1;
      p->next = NULL;

    }
  }
  return head;
}*/

void printList(list head){
  list traversal = head;
  while(traversal->next != NULL){
    printf("%s", traversal->word);
    traversal = traversal->next;
  }
}

void insert(char* dest, char* toAdd){
  strcpy(dest, toAdd);
}

int compare(char* str1, char* str2){
  int value = strcmp(str1, str2);
  return value;
}

/* I wrote this function to collect words to use */
int getNextWord(char* output){
  int c;
  int i = 0;
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == ',')
      break;
    else{
      output[i++] = c;
    }
  }
  output[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Now is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Not only to catch and locate the crash, but also to help you step through the code to actually see what it's doing.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a good time to start learning how to use a debugger. You could run your program in GDB and see where your crash happens.

Comment: Another general tip: Don't do to much at once. Create your program iteratively, adding one little feature at a time with plenty of testing in between to make sure it works before starting on the next thing.

Comment: Are you aware that parameters in C are passed by value? You will never change the value of `head` in `main` function.

Comment: By the way, it's good that you don't use the `length` variable in the `main` function, as it will not be correct inside that loop.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**

When you make a new `struct LinkedList` (i.e. in function `createNode`) you only get a char-pointer for the member `word` and it is uninitialized (i.e. not pointing to valid memory).

But then you do:

insert(head->word, entry);

which is really a string copy into `head->word`. So you are using an uninitialized pointer as destination. That is undefined behavior.

You need to `malloc` some memory for `word` before copying to it (or use `strdup` if available).

**Problem 2:**

```
void addEntry(list head, char* entry)
```

You pass `head` as a pointer value. Inside the function you change `head`. However, any change you make to `head` inside the function is "lost" when the function returns. In other words - `head` in the calling function will **not** be changed. That is (most likely) not what you want.

I guess you want:

```
void addEntry(list* head, char* entry)
```

When you do that you need to use `head` in a different way inside the function, i.e. `*head` instead. Example:

```
  if(*head == NULL){
    *head = temp;
    insert((*head)->word, entry);
    printf("head->word = %s", (*head)->word);
    // p->next->word = NULL;   REMOVE THIS LINE
    return;
  }
```

and the call in `main`

```
addEntry(&head, line);
```

BTW: typedef'ing `list` to be a pointer is normally considered a bad idea. If you really want to typedef a pointer at least give it a name that tells it is pointer. Like: `typedef struct LinkedList *pLinkedList;`

**Problem 3:**

You never initialize `count`. So here

```
p->count = p->count + 1;
```

you use an uninitialized variable. Again undefined behavior.

**Problem 4:**

Take a look at this code:

```
  list temp, p;           // p is uninitialized
  temp = createNode();
  if(head == NULL){
    head = temp;
    insert(head->word, entry);
    printf("head->word = %s", head->word);
    p->next->word = NULL;   // Here p is used but it still uninitialized !!
    return;
  }
```

Again this is undefined behavior

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the quick feedback. I initialized word in the struct by making it word[50] and count in the createNode() by setting temp->count -0;. Furthermore, I can see that the program no longer crashes right away. However, I added a way to stop the input when it reads 'stop' and that gets the program to crash. I am not sure what to do about addEntry since when I changed it to list* head as opposed to list head I got a lot more errors. Sorry for being such a noob, I've only just started learning. About the fourth problem, I meant to type head but I put p instead by mistake.

Comment: @AbdulazizAl-Boainain I have added some extra explanation